# Generating A record with $ GENERATE

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns

To generate PTR reverse records with $GENERATE, we can do so

```
$GENERATE 1-255 $ PTR 168-121-40-$.isp.domain.net.
```

but now how to generate A record of type

```
 168-121-40-1.isp IN A 168.121.40.1
 168-121.40.2.isp IN A 168.121.40.2
 ...
 168-121.40.255.isp IN A 168.121.40.255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite similar I think, the <kbd>$</kbd> template can be used more than once:

```
$GENERATE 1-255 168-121-40-$.isp. IN A 168.121.40.$
```

Comment: In fact it's used more than once in the original PTR example ; )